# anchor tag "target" attribute is not working

Tags: html

Here is the anchor tag with `target="FrameMain"`

```
            <a href="UserSelection.aspx" id="UserLink" target="FrameMain" runat="server">
            <asp:Literal id="UserLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal></a>
```

Frame tag

```
      <FRAME SRC="HomePagePP1.aspx" name="FrameMain" runat="server" id="FrameMain" frameborder="0" />
```

In this, the target attribute does not work in modern browsers such as chrome and firefox but works in IE. It is navigation into new window tab instead  within the frame. What could be the issue?

Comment: Why the "JavaScript" tag?

Comment: it may helps using javascript also

Comment: Please share your javascript

Comment: there is no javascript for this

Comment: have you tried targeting the `id` instead of the `name`?

Comment: yes.. but didn't worked.. :-(  @ickyrr

Comment: is it possible for you to show your code here? So we can find out where the problem is.

Comment: please check this fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/Sanjay_Net/8rgbt5c2/12/ , which was I am looking too.. w3schools content should be appear in the frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"target" attribute will not work in some browsers. Try like this.. hope it works..

```
 <a href="javascript:void(window.parent.document.getElementById('FrameMain').src='UserSelection.aspx')" id="UserLink" runat="server">
```

Answer (score 0):

> Deprecated This feature has been removed from the Web. Though some
>   browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped.
>   Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may
>   break at any time.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame